# What happens when answers with more than 600 characters are converted to comments?

Tags: support, comments

I noticed that Sklivvz said he converted [this answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/7158/898) to a comment, but it didn't appear in the comments above. The answer itself was about 660 characters, which leads me to believe that Sklivvz used an SE feature to convert the answer to a comment, but the SE feature didn't check to see if it would fit in a comment (or didn't notify Sklivvz that the conversion failed). Maybe someone should look into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The convert-to-comment works even with longer answers, it just cuts them off after the limit. The conversion worked fine, also in this case.

What you can't see is that the comment was later deleted by me, in response to a flag on that comment. In my opinion, the comment didn't add any value, it was more of a rant and I would have outright deleted it myself instead of converting it. The flag indicated that at least one other user shared my opinion, so I went ahead and deleted the comment.

Comment: I see... Thanks.